# How to add a toolTip to a valuePicker

Tags: tooltip, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an Ext Lib valuePicker on an XPage and then have added an Ext Lib toolTip to the Xpage and specified the id of the valuePicker in the for property of the toolTip (it shows up in the list of controls to aim the toolTip at, but when I hover over the valuePicker nothing happens. I have several toolTips on the page aiming at radio buttons and edit boxes and they all work correctly so my process is correct. I aim the toolTip that I want for the valuePicker to an edit control and I get the correct tip displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valuePicker "loses" it id during rendering (look at rendered page's source code) so it is not possible to address valuePicker's id in tooltip.

A workaround is to put a `<span>` with an id around the valuePicker and to address this id in tooltip.

```xml
<span
    id="valuePickerTooltip">
    <xe:valuePicker
        id="valuePicker"
        ...>
        <xe:this.dataProvider>
            ...
        </xe:this.dataProvider>
    </xe:valuePicker>
</span>
<xe:tooltip
    id="tooltip1"
    for="valuePickerTooltip"
    label="this is the tooltip">
</xe:tooltip>
```

Comment: This looks like it should work and it's pretty simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can compute the "for" property for the xe:tooltip to use getClientId("valuePickerTooltip").

Without having this tested, I'm pretty sure the "valuePickerTooltip" id will be converted to a client ID at runtime, that means it gets a prefix. With getClientId() you can get the runtime ID for a control.

Comment: No, unfortunately, there is no client ID. valuePicker gets rendered to something like this: `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="return XSP.selectValue('extlib.dijit.PickerList',...)"><img src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/icons/iconValuePicker.png" alt="Open Picker"></a>`

Comment: but the valuePicker is bound to an input control, isn't it? One could bind the tooltip to the input control. Otherwise your solution with the wrapping span tag should be the solution, indeed.

Comment: Bill mentioned in his question that his tooltip works for edit control already and is looking for a solution for valuePicker. Property "for" works well if the target control has a client id. That is the case for most controls. valuePicker is an exception though.